# iPhone find image format supported by ios programmatically

Tags: iphone

Can any one tell me how to programmatically find the image formats supported by iOS in the iPhone SDK?

Comment: http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/

Answer (score 3):

The docs list the supported image formats.

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIImage_Class/Reference/Reference.html

```
Tagged Image File Format (TIFF) .tiff, .tif 
Joint Photographic Experts Group (JPEG) .jpg, .jpeg  
Graphic Interchange Format (GIF) .gif 
Portable Network Graphic (PNG) .png 
Windows Bitmap Format (DIB) .bmp, .BMPf 
Windows Icon Format .ico 
Windows Cursor .cur
XWindow bitmap .xbm
```

Answer (score 0):

On Mac OS X, you can call `[[NSImage class] imageFileTypes]` to get the supported image file types, but the `UIImage` class for iOS doesn't seem to have a similar function.