# UIImage is empty after calling imageWithContentsOfFile

Tags: ios

[image]
As you can see, that I have put my the national flags in a folder in Xcode and I am trying to display it to the navigation bar. However, it is not showing up and I found out:

`NSString *imageName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@.icns",countryName];
    UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:imageName];`

image is "nil".

Any idea? Thanks!

Comment: Where was the image path you are sending NSString to here `UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:imageName` send the path to that method. or make like this `UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:[NSString stringwithFormat:@"%@.icns",countryName]];`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use like this

```
 NSString *imageName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@.icns",countryName];
 UIImage *image =  [UIImage imageNamed:imageName];
```

Please Try This

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9156501/iphone-find-image-format-supported-by-ios-programmatically
Please check your image format.

Answer (score 1):

Check whether the file actually exists. I suspect it doesn't. Use `[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:`.

Comment: i found out the reason from Anjaly's answer.

Answer (score 1):

Where was the image path you are sending NSString to here

```
 UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:imageName
```

send the path to that method. or make like this

```
 UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:[NSString stringwithFormat:@"%@.icns",countryName]];
```

Comment: I tried this as well, the result is the same - what could be some other reasons?